# No cambia el color

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ts

Estoy haciendo un proyecto en Angular y por ende tengo que usar TypeScript. Nunca usé JS o TS antes así que no entiendo bien como funciona. En uno de los componentes, quiero que cuando presionen uno de los dos títulos, el color del título clickeado pase de "#ff6466" a "#3b2e42" y se mantenga así. Mientras que el otro título que no fue clickeado siempre mantenga el color "#ff6466". Es decir, nunca tienen que tener el color "#3b2e42" al mismo tiempo.
El problema es que siempre no me marca ningún error pero tampoco funciona.
Cómo debería verse si presioné "SOFT SKILLS"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cómo en realidad se ve cuando presioné "SOFT SKILLS"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
TYPESCRIPT:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HardSkillsComponent } from './hard-skills.component';

describe('HardSkillsComponent', () => {
  let component: HardSkillsComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<HardSkillsComponent>;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ HardSkillsComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(HardSkillsComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});

/*-----*/

function clickeaSkill(){
  var hard = document.getElementById("tituloHard");
  var soft = document.getElementById("tituloSoft");
  if (hard != null) {
    hard.onclick= colorHardOscuro;
    colorSoftClaro();
  }
  if (soft != null) {
    soft.onclick= colorSoftOscuro;
    colorHardClaro();
  }
}

function colorSoftClaro(){
  var soft = document.getElementById("tituloSoft");
  if (soft != null) {
    soft.style.color="#ff6466";
  }
}
function colorHardClaro(){
  var hard = document.getElementById("tituloHard");
  if (hard != null) {
    hard.style.color="#ff6466";
  }
}
function colorSoftOscuro(){
  var soft = document.getElementById("tituloSoft");
  if (soft != null) {
    soft.style.color="#3b2e42";
  }
}
function colorHardOscuro(){
  var hard = document.getElementById("tituloHard");
  if (hard != null) {
    hard.style.color="#3b2e42";
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
 /*  #fa4347  #ff6466 #3b2e42  #423549*/
section{
    background-color: #fa4347;
}

#tituloHard, #tituloSoft{
    font-size:50px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    color:#ff6466;
}

#tituloHard:hover, #tituloSoft:hover{
    color: #423549;
}
```

HTML5 CON BOOTSTRAP:

```
 <section>

    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3 id="tituloHard">HARD SKILLS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                <h3 id="tituloSoft">SOFT SKILLS</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <article>
        <div id="skills">
            <p>repollo</p>
        </div>
    </article>

</section>
```

INDEX DEL PROYECTO ANGULAR:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<base href="/">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<meta name="keywords" content="carolina,portafolio,porfolio,portfolio,web,website,página,pagina,sitio,web,app">
<meta name="author" content="Carolina">
<title>Carolina Portfolio</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Limelight&family=Montserrat:wght@700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
puedes hacer de la siguiente forma. sé que hay varias formas, pero traté de que sea lo mas parecido a lo que intentabas hacer.
```

```js
 clickeaSkill() {
    var hard = document.getElementById("tituloHard");
    var soft = document.getElementById("tituloSoft");
    var self = this; // creamos una variable en donde guardamos this para poder usarlo luego.
  
    if (hard != null) {
      hard.addEventListener('click', function() { // en ts o js puesdes usar addEventListener para agregar un evento a un elemento html
        self.colorHardOscuro(); // de esta forma usamos la variable que creamos en ves de this
        self.colorSoftClaro(); // 
      });
    }
    if (soft != null) {
      soft.addEventListener('click', function() {
        self.colorHardClaro();
        self.colorSoftOscuro();
      });
    }
  }
  
  

  colorSoftClaro() {
    var soft = document.getElementById("tituloSoft");
    if (soft != null) {
      soft.style.color = "#ff6466";
    }
  }
  colorHardClaro() {
    var hard = document.getElementById("tituloHard");
    if (hard != null) {
      hard.style.color = "#ff6466";
    }
  }
  colorSoftOscuro() {
    var soft = document.getElementById("tituloSoft");
    if (soft != null) {
      soft.style.color = "#3b2e42";
    }
  }
  colorHardOscuro() {
    var hard = document.getElementById("tituloHard");
    if (hard != null) {
      hard.style.color = "#3b2e42";
    }

  }
```

```html
<html>
<section>


    <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: red;">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3 id="tituloHard" style="color:#ff6466">HARD SKILLS</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4">
                <h3 id="tituloSoft">SOFT SKILLS</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <article>
        <div id="skills">
            <p>repollo</p>
        </div>
    </article>

</section>
</html>
```

í

Answer (score 0):

le realicé unos pequeños cambios a tu código del js...

```
let hard = document.getElementById( "tituloHard" );
let soft = document.getElementById( "tituloSoft" );
soft.addEventListener( "click", funb );
hard.addEventListener( "click", funa );

function funa() {  
    colorHardOscuro();
    colorSoftClaro();
}

function funb() {   
    colorSoftOscuro();
    colorHardClaro(); 
}

function colorSoftClaro() {
    soft.style.color="#ff6466";
}

function colorHardClaro() {
    hard.style.color="#ff6466";
}

function colorSoftOscuro() {
    soft.style.color="#3b2e42";
}

function colorHardOscuro() {
    hard.style.color="#3b2e42";
}
```

Como verás, le agregue unos listeners a los títulos, para registrar el "click" y obrar en consecuencia.
También quité las multiples instanciaciones de "hard" y "soft", así como los if/null, que no tenian sentido.

Para hacerlo funcionar quité todo lo correspondiente a TYPESCRIPT, no porque este mal (no tengo ni idea), sino porque me arrojaba un error con los imports.

Tendrías que fijarte en el css, ya que tienes un Hover, que cambia los colores de los títulos y estaría como en conflicto.

Espero que te sirva de algo.